# LRtest - Split vector doesn't allow NA's

Tags: r

I'm currently running LRtest (Rasch-Model, eRm-R-package) and need to split my group with an external splitcriterien (median of population density per km^2)
a few persons didn't answer and R error is:

```
lrt8 <- LRtest (res, splitcr = splitresid)
```

> Error in LRtest.Rm(res, splitcr = splitresid) :    Split vector should
>   not contain NA's

how can i throw these NA's out or replace them with median etc??

Ps: my tests run ultra long (3h for a sample of 400 persons with 100 items) is this normal???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is

```
library(eRm)
library(zoo)
res <- raschdat1_RM_fitted   # using the example from `?LRtest`
splitvec <- sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE)
splitvec[2:3] <- NA # insert some NA
lrres <- LRtest(res, splitcr = splitvec)
```

> Error in LRtest.Rm(res, splitcr = splitvec) : 
>         Split vector should not contain NA's

Replace the `NA` with `median` using `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
lrres <- LRtest(res, splitcr = as.integer(na.aggregate(splitvec, median)))
```